# FileOutputStream throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, file, java-io

I am trying to create a new file along with directory but when I call "fos = new FileOutputStream(file);" it throws file not found error always.
Here is the code

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
String getName = "User";
String filePath="D:/New file";
File file;
Date date = new Date();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String headerDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);

try {
  WritableWorkbook w = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream);
  WritableSheet s = w.createSheet("Report generate", 0);
  s.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "New File" + getName));
  s.addCell(new Label(0, 2, "Response Date: " + headerDate));
  w.write();
  w.close();

  String resultFileName = "NewFileToGenerate" +getName+headerDate+ ".xls";
  String fileName = filePath.concat(resultFileName);
  file = new File(fileName);
  file.mkdirs();
  file.createNewFile();
  fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  baos = outputStream;
  // Put data in your baos
  baos.writeTo(fos);

} catch (Exception e) {

} finally {
  outputStream.close();
  fos.close();
}
```

Here I have filepath but inside that filePath I have to create another folder by appending date in it and then I have to save file.

Here is the stackTrace

D:/New file/NewFileToGenerateUser26/2018 20:00:14.xls (Is a directory)

Comment: Please can you post also the stacktrace? It often helps a lot to understand what's going on ;)

Comment: This will happen if the File refers to a directory and not a regular file.

Comment: @Alexandre edit with the stacktrace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you used

```
file.makeDirs();
```

It created all the non-existent directories including `"NewFileToGenerate" +getName+headerDate+ ".xls"`. Yes, the file you wanted to create is created as a directory.

And then you called file.createNewFile(), which will return false because a directory with the same name as the file exists.

Trying to use FileOutputStream with a directory won't work, an exception will be thrown.

Hence, you will see this error message:
    D:/New file/NewFileToGenerateUser26/2018 20:00:14.xls (Is a directory)

Possible Fix:

Create the parent directory first, and then create the file you wanted to create after the parent directory is created in a different statement. 
Such as:

```
File file = new File("parent1/parent2");
file.mkDirs();

File desiredFile = new File("parent1/parent2/desiredfile.extensionhere");
desiredFile.createNewFile();
```

Comment: but why I don't get any directory or file created

Comment: It should be... check again

Comment: Yeah it is getting created with the .xls name directory is getting created 
what to do to create a new folder and a new directory as well with date.

Comment: @HarshKumrawat use `"MM_dd_yyyy-HH_mm_ss"` as format.

Comment: @JoopEggen I was looking for this thing too. Great this helps

Answer (score 2):

As said by BrokenEarth, you have created a directory with the name of the file that you wanted to create. So you should proceed in two steps:

1. create the destination directory
2. create the file inside the directory

To do such a thing, you may do something like:

```
String filePath = "D:" + File.separator + "someDir";
File dir = new File(filePath);
if (dir.exists() || dir.mkdirs()) {
    // assuming that resultFileName contains the absolute file name, including the directory in which it should go
    File destFile = new File(resultFileName);
    if (destFile.exists() || destFile.createNewFile()) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Should prob check if the dir already exists similar to my answer?

Comment: @Rab: yes fo sure, as mkdirs() would return false is the directory already exists - I added the checks

Answer (score 1):

The name of the exception is misleading, but stems from not being able to write to / create that file.

The reason is that you are using a `/` in the file name, which is a path separator. Even Windows with its `\` also maintains the Posix standard and does not allow it.

Comment: Java translates / to \ on Windows.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In cmd.exe one can also use `/` (POSIX). So java does it too? And that with me having years of experience in java. One learns

Answer (score 1):

Your file is getting created as a directory I have fixed your code and added comments

```
    File root = new File(filePath);
    //Check if root exists if not create it
    if(!root.exists()) root.mkdirs();
    String resultFileName = "NewFileToGenerate" +getName+headerDate+ ".xls";
    File xlsFile = new File(root, resultFileName);
    //check if xls File exists if not create it
    if(!xlsFile.exists()) {
        try {
            xlsFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```